# Where to put the user information in the session

Tags: spring-security, redis, spring-boot

I have spring boot code to authenticate the use from database. It generates the x-auth token or a session.External redis server is managing the sessions , how would I put the user information in the session , so that other user can't modify the data of any other users they would be cross checked to whom the session belongs.

Here is the code snippet :

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {  

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
          builder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource())
        .usersByUsernameQuery(
            "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");          

    }
```

Also I would like to restrict the login to only one web service , which will be generating the x-auth token , Other web services would be disabled for generating the tokens.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Redis. Let's assume user has an id (user.id = toto12)
You should perform the check of user's on server side and not on client side.

Process to check serverside:
1. check auth jdbcTemplate as you do,

2. then, get the user logged in and compare with user that tries to login in REDIS.  If empty,  create a new record in Redis [for exemple  auth:users:toto12 = sessionid] for example.
3. if all these tests works, return the token assuming that user  has  rights to be logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [Spring Cloud Security](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/)? Also [User Account and Authentication Server](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa) may be useful. It can handle the case that you described:

> restrict the login to only one web service , which will be generating the x-auth token , Other web services would be disabled for generating the tokens.

For the sessions use case check out [Spring Session](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/) project. It supports Redis too.

> I have spring boot code to authenticate the use from database. It
>   generates the x-auth token or a session.External redis server is
>   managing the sessions , how would I put the user information in the
>   session , so that other user can't modify the data of any other users
>   they would be cross checked to whom the session belongs.

Comment: I think http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/findbyusername.html , should be the solution

Answer (score 0):

I went through this tutorial , http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/findbyusername.html , this link has the tutorial for user identification.